# How to create a pivot table where both the index and the column are the unique values of the same df column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a df as follows:

```
QUESTIONCODE      SUBJETCS
    1            English  
    1            French
    2            English
    3            Japanese
    4            English
    4            Japanese
```

And I would like to create a pivot table where both the index and the column would be my SUBJECTS unique values from df, and it would be filled by the number of QUESTIONCODE's belonging to the combination of SUBJECTs represented by each index and column. Then, the result would be:

```
         English      French        Japanese
English     3            1              1
French      1            1              0
Japanese    1            0              2
```

I have already tried some ways using pandas functions as groupby, pivot_table and crosstab, but I still could not get the result shown above.

Could anyone please help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution, but by no means it is the best solution. I believe it will allow to get started. I provided some comments with the code. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import collections

# this is your data
df = pd.DataFrame({"QUESTIONCODE": [1,1,2,3,4,4], 
                   "SUBJETCS": ["English", "French", "English", "Japanese", "English", "Japanese"]})
df["SUBJETCS_"] = df["SUBJETCS"] # I am duplicating the subject column here

# pivoting to get the counts of each subject
dfPivot = df.pivot_table(index="SUBJETCS", columns="SUBJETCS_", values="QUESTIONCODE", aggfunc=["count"], fill_value=0).reset_index()
dfPivot.columns = ["SUBJETCS"] + sorted(df["SUBJETCS"].unique())

x = df.groupby("QUESTIONCODE")["SUBJETCS"].apply(",".join).reset_index() # for each QUESTIONCODE taking its subjects as a DataFrame
dictCombos = dict(zip(x["QUESTIONCODE"].tolist(), [s.split(",") for s in x["SUBJETCS"].tolist()])) # this will map QUESTIONCODE to its subject as a dictionary

list_all_pairs = [] # this will have all possible pair of subjects

for k, v in dictCombos.items():
#     v = list(set(v.split(",")))
    prm = list(itertools.permutations(v, 2))
    list_all_pairs.extend(prm)

dictMap = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(dfPivot.columns[1:])} # just maps each subject to an index
dictCounts = dict(collections.Counter(list_all_pairs)) # dictionary of all pairs to its counts

dictCoords = {} # indexing each subjects i.e. English 0, French 1, ..., this will allow to load as matrix

for pairs, counts in dictCounts.items():
    coords = (dictMap[pairs[0]], dictMap[pairs[1]])
    dictCoords[coords] = counts

x = dfPivot.iloc[:, 1:].values # saving the content of the pivot into an 2 dimensional array
for coords, counts in dictCoords.items():
    x[coords[0], coords[1]] = counts

dfCounts = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=dfPivot.columns[1:]) # loading the content of array into a DataFrame
df = pd.concat([dfPivot.iloc[:, 0], dfCounts], axis=1) # and finally putting it all together
```

Comment: It really helped me! I could adapt it to a project I am working on. I basically used your code, but I improved it a little bit by cutting some parts I found unnecessary! I will post it below so that you can see the changes I made.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That's the code I mentioned on the comment of griggy's ANSWER!

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import collections

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"QUESTIONCODE": [1,1,2,3,4,4], 
                   "SUBJETCS": ["English", "French", "English", "Japanese", "English", "Japanese"]})


# Pivoting to get the counts of each subject
dfPivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='QUESTIONCODE', index='SUBJETCS', columns='SUBJETCS', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

# Creating a dataframe with each QUESTIONCODE and its SUBJECTs
x = df.groupby("QUESTIONCODE")["SUBJETCS"].apply(",".join).reset_index() 

# Mapping QUESTIONCODE to its SUBJECTs as a dictionary
dictCombos = dict(zip(x["QUESTIONCODE"].tolist(), [s.split(",") for s in x["SUBJETCS"].tolist()])) 

# Creating a list with all possible pair of SUBJECTs
list_all_pairs = []
for k, v in dictCombos.items():
    prm = list(itertools.permutations(v, 2))
    list_all_pairs.extend(prm)

# Creating a dictionary of all pairs of Materias and its counts
dictCounts = dict(collections.Counter(list_all_pairs)) 

# Filling the dfPivot dataframe with all pairs of Materias and its counts
for pairs, counts in dictCounts.items():
    dfPivot.loc[pairs] = counts
```